# Laravel 6.0 authentication error : Argument 3 passed to Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::doVerify() must be an instance of Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

My backend project is based on Laravel 6.0 and I want to test the logout API in postman.

I am using the `Jwt middleware` for user authentication.

I already run the following commands.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan key:generate
php artisan jwt:secret
```

But still occurs this error:

```
Argument 3 passed to Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::doVerify() must be an instance of Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key
```

Here is my `jwt` middleware.

```
class Jwt extends BaseMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Invalid']);
            }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Expired']);
            }else{
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Authorization Token not found']);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Here is my route file for APIs.

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'namespace' => 'API\User', 'middleware' => ['assign.guard:users']], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.verify'], function () {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    });
});
```

And here is the logout function of AuthController.

```
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => 'Only authorize users can see this message',
        ]);
    }
```

And, finally, here is the postman screenshot to test API:

[image]

Hope your help.

Comment: to help the reader please edit your question after reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)

Comment: please show your jwt verify middleware, also you not using request variable in logout